# Yesterday I made a tron ​transaction but I never got it verified by etherscan and it appears but in my balance

Tags: etherscan, address.transfer

Yesterday I made a tron ​​transaction but I never got it verified by etherscan and it appears but [in my balance](https://etherscan.io/address/0xd636059901d60d2f2035b461c0d5db45ca9d939f#tokentxns) **it does not appear what should I do?**
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you're asking what I think you're asking, you should click this:

(ETH and token balances are two separate things.)

[image]

Comment: no, they appear as envoys but the transfer never came

I do not know what to do if the direction of the wallet was fine

Answer (score 0):

Token balances are not shown on the primary address page in etherscan. Click the "View Tokens" dropdown to see [your token balances](https://etherscan.io/token/0xf230b790e05390fc8295f4d3f60332c93bed42e2?a=0xd636059901d60d2f2035b461c0d5db45ca9d939f).

Comment: no, they appear as envoys but the transfer never came

I do not know what to do if the direction of the wallet was fine

Comment: @johnlizarazu: The token balance on that page shows `2,252.186298 TRX` - what is it you're expecting to see?

Comment: If I understand you, my question is: how do I get these token into my wallet, there it appears as if they had been sent but they never came to me, is there a way or should I wait or have I lost them?

Comment: @johnlizarazu: The tokens are in wallet `0xd636059901d60d2f2035b461c0d5db45ca9d939f`. Is this not your wallet?

Comment: yes, if that is my wallet in the HITBTC exchange but the question is why it does not reflect that balance is as if they had never arrived

Comment: You'd have to ask HitBTC about that. The tokens are in that wallet according to the Ethereum blockchain.

Comment: if I'm in it but your customer service is very slow I've been asking for two days and they just tell me that the engineers are already checking
likewise, thank you very much, it will be waiting for me to tell me hit btc, unfortunately, I lost my good fortune today with the token